# While writing an article in latex, the automatic \newpage does not work

Tags: latex

[image]

Even if I use the following command at the beginning of the article (this is my documentclass) I have to insert \newpage every time by hand. Is it normal? How can I fix this problem?

```
\usepackage [a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
    \textheight=5000px                    % Saving trees ;-)
\usepackage{url}
```

Comment: Why do you use pixel as measure instead of cm?

Comment: @byebye If you want to save trees, have a look at the `savetrees` package :) https://www.ctan.org/pkg/savetrees

Answer (score 1):

You are forcing the document to have a textheigth of 5000 pixels, which correspond to 176 cm, more or less: this means that LaTeX is optimizing the text to fill a space in the page whose heigth is 176 cm.

If you want to save space (and paper!) just set the `geometry` package, removing the `\textheigth` option: set the margins as you prefer, taking into account that the document should be pleasent to see.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage [a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-102]
\end{document}
```

Reducing the margin automatically enlarges the space for text in the page in a more safe way.

Instead of using the options `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `rigth` you may use the option

```
\usepackage [a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
```

to set all them to the same value.

Comment: thanks, honestly I didn't even know the meaning of 5000 px

Comment: @byebye Just a little advice: search for the options you include in your preamble to be sure that they are actually useful. If my answer solved the problem, mark it as accepted for future users.